# Hiding Rows Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro in Excel VBA whereas any row under C2 gets hidden if the cell text contains "hide". I want the entire column to be evaluated no matter how many cells are filled (hence why LastRow is goes until the end). Don't know why this isn't working - it tells me I have a type mismatch. Can someone help pls

```
Sub Hide()
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            StartRow = Range("C2")
            LastRow = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
        For i = StartRow To LastRow
            If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "hide" Then
                    Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Else
                    Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `iCol`?

Comment: `xlDown` is not a great way to get the last row. All it takes is one cell in that column that is missing a value and it will base the last row on that missing value.

Comment: Is the value of `Cells(i, iCol).Value` a number? If so, you are comparing it to a `String`, which would mean the types do not match.

Answer (score 1):

you have some issues in your code:

- `StartRow` and `LastRow` are not relates to `Integer` or `Long`, you implicitly defined them as `Range` because `row` property for the `Range("C2")` and `Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))` not specified;
- `Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))` will return correct range only in case when range will not contains empty cells, otherwise it will return range from `C2` to last not empty cell in column `C`;
- `iCol` not defined in your code, so it need to be changed to something like `iCol = Range("C2").Column`;

your updated code below:

```
Sub Hide()
    Dim StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long, iCol As Long, cl As Range
    Set cl = Range("C2") 'start range
    iCol = cl.Column
    StartRow = cl.Row
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "hide" Then
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

additional variant how you can achieve desired result:

```
Sub Hide2()
    Dim checkRng As Range, cl As Range
    Set checkRng = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In checkRng
        If cl.Value <> "hide" Then
            cl.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```